# np.log in a for loop, I always get TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I have a really easy dataset with just one column, and I would like to have a for loop over each row of the dataframe so that for each row it calculate the log of `current_close_price/first_row_close_price`. Whatever I do, it says:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
price.head()

               Close
Date    
2010-07-19  107.290001
2010-07-20  108.480003
2010-07-21  107.070000
2010-07-22  109.459999
2010-07-23  110.410004


for index, row in price.iterrows():
  first_row_price=price.iloc[0,0]
  current_price=price.iloc[index,0]
  log_rt = np.log(current_price / reference_price)
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code I suspect you have something like np.log = x. The code you've shown here will not induce that error

Answer (score -1):

Consider we have the table in `a.csv` file, which have two columns *Date* and *Close*, and writing `first_row_price` instead of `reference_price` in your code:

```
with open("a.csv", 'r') as a:
    price = pd.read_csv(a, usecols=[1])  # which get data related to 'Close' column

    for index, row in price.iterrows():
        first_row_price = price.iloc[0, 0]
        current_price = price.iloc[index, 0]
        log_rt = np.log(current_price / first_row_price)
```

This code will get output as:

```
0.0
0.011030393877764241
-0.002052631799009411
0.020023718610826604
0.02866528771045947
```